# Winforms graphics function

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm working on a winforms project where I need to draw tiled images. So far this is what I have:

Update method (hooked to a timer.tick event) :

```
        int elapsedTime = Environment.TickCount - lastTick;

        tempLevel.Update(elapsedTime);
        Invalidate();
        lbl_fps.Text = "FPS: " + FPSHandler.CalculateFrameRate();

        lastTick = Environment.TickCount;
```

Paint method:

```
        public void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicManager.drawTiledImage(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(0,0,level.Length,1024), "paper");
            for (int i = 1; i < 800; i ++)
            {
                GraphicManager.drawLine(e.Graphics,
                    new PointF(i + GraphicManager.winpos.x - 1, level[(int)(i + GraphicManager.winpos.x - 1)] + 400),
                    new PointF(i + GraphicManager.winpos.x, level[(int)(i + GraphicManager.winpos.x)] + 400));
            }
        }
```

drawTiledImage method:

```
            ImageAttributes imgA = new ImageAttributes();
            imgA.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.Tile);

            g.DrawImage(images[image], 
                ExtraMath.fromRect(
                new Rectangle(
                    (int)Math.Round(rect.X - winPos.x),
                    (int)Math.Round(rect.Y - winPos.y), 
                    rect.Width, rect.Height)),

                new Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgA);
```

winpos is a vector, a custom class similar to PointF, except with more features, and uses floating point numbers to store x/y, and is convertible to floats, Points, and PointFs.

When I run this code, it appears to work until I begin to scroll down, and the screen looks like this:
[image: Glitch]

it should look like this (minus the line):
[image: preferred look]

Any help?

Extra info: 
- the winPos is basically a wrapped version of PointF that has more operators and such
- The glitch appears very aggressively whenever winpos.y approaches the height of the image
- The glitch does not happen when scrolling to the left/right

Comment: Can we do this without having to guess what's wrong please?  The code completely doesn't match the screenshot.

Comment: Where are you getting your graphics context from for `g`?  Is it a new image every time or are you reusing the same image you wrote to on previous calls?

Comment: the image is stored in a  dictionary of static images in the class GraphicManager, so the method only needs the name (as a string) of the texture to draw. the textures stay the same once the form is loaded and the images are loaded into the dictionairy.